# Can JSON.loads unshorten URL during loads?

Tags: json, python-3.x

Greeting

I am using JSNO.loads to read json line from a text file, one of key-value pair contains a text that has a shortened URL.

Would it be possible to unshorten these URLS **while executing the JSON.loads** ?

if this is possible, it would save  parsing the text and extracting each URLS in order to unshorten it !!

Any feedback ?

Comment: You could potentially use the [`JSONDecoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) _object_pairs_hook_ - but I don't think it will save you any processing time.